# google_oath2 400: invalid_request on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, google-oauth, credentials

I'm having this issue trying to sign in with Google:

Error 400: invalid_request
Missing required parameter: client_id

I have already made sure by password is correctly encrypted via Vim. For some reason, my GitHub OAuth works normally.

Here's the Devise config for both:

```
  config.omniauth :github, "#{Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:github][:client]}", "#{Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:github][:secret]}", scope: 'user,public_repo'

  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "#{Rails.application.credentials.dig(:google_oauth2, :client_id)}", "#{Rails.application.credentials.dig(:google_oauth2, :client_secret)}"
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!